# Tailwind CSS : Is there a way to target next sibling?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a radio input with a label like the one below. Input is hidden and a label is used to make a visually appealing circle on which the user can click.

```html
<input id="choice-yes" type="radio" class="opacity-0 w-0 fixed"/>
<label for="choice-yes" class="transition  duration-500 bg-blue-300 hover:bg-blue-500 w-20 h-20 rounded-full mr-5 flex items-center align-middle justify-center">Yes</label>
```

When the user clicks on the label input gets checked. I'm trying to figure out how to target that, so I could give the label a different style.

This can be achieved in pure CSS using the next sibling selector.

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: #bfb !important;
  border-color: #4c4 !important;
}
```

Is there something similar in tailwind.css that I could use instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For those looking to implement this, since introduction of just-in-time mode (Tailwind CSS v2.1+) [sibling selector variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#sibling-selector-variants) is available.

Comment: v3+ https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state

Comment: I came here for exactly what OP was asking and I think this answer is misleading. TW does not have a utility using the Adjacent (next) Sibling Selector as of v3. Differentiated Peer utilities may work for the the same purpose, but they don't use adjacent sibling either. You would need to use [&+label] type stuff as Sanka explained below.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a [complex variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#complex-variants) I wrote for this purpose (tested with tailwindcss `2.0.1`)

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

const focusedSiblingPlugin = plugin(function ({ addVariant, e }) {
  addVariant("focused-sibling", ({ container }) => {
    container.walkRules((rule) => {
      rule.selector = `:focus + .focused-sibling\\:${rule.selector.slice(1)}`;
    });
  });
});

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [focusedSiblingPlugin],
  variants: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ["focused-sibling"],
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Also works for Tailwind `1.9`! Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 11):

You can use arbitrary values to target sibling elements.

```
[&:checked+label]:bg-[#bfb]
```

(For demo purposes I used a checkbox)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<input id="choice-yes" type="checkbox" class="opacity-0 w-0 fixed [&:checked+label]:bg-[#bfb]"/>
<label for="choice-yes" class="transition  duration-500 bg-blue-300 hover:bg-blue-500 w-20 h-20 rounded-full mr-5 flex items-center align-middle justify-center">Yes</label>
```

Comment: Thx! This is the only answer which implements the [Adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+` operator) with tailwindcss and without a plugin. The mentioned [`peer-*` classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state) uses the [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~` operator).

Comment: @PutziSan I think this is the right answer because `peer-*` using `~` which may affect to the elements at the same time using `+` only effect to the next element only

Answer (score 5):

There isn't anything built into Tailwind presently.  The closest feature would be [Pseudo-Class Variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants#checked) of which there is a "checked" prefix.  But that would only apply to the radio itself.  In order to target siblings you'd need to write your own [complex variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#complex-variants) and then you could do something like

```html
<input id="choice-yes" type="radio"/>
<label for="choice-yes" class="bg-gray-100 sibling-checked:bg-blue-500">Yes</label>
```

Comment: I wonder if we could have a sibling variant:
`sibling:checked:bg-blue-500`

Answer (score 2):

You can use group-hover for this situation.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged as links may break rendering the answer meaningless. Please summarize the linked information to help future readers. Link-only answers may be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've been wondering the same and since I've created my own variants since my Tailwind debut, I thought I could create a quick one for you.

My problem with previous answers is that the class is focused on the sibling. The class should be appended to the first item and used as such :

```html
<input id="choice-yes" type="radio" class="nextOnChecked:bg-blue-500 nextOnChecked:border-blue-800"/>
```

The code for the [variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuring-variants) should be something like :

```js
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin");

const nextOnChecked = plugin(function ({ addVariant, e }) {
  addVariant('nextOnChecked', ({ modifySelectors, separator }) => {
    modifySelectors(({ className }) => {
      return `.${e(`nextOnChecked${separator}${className}`)}:checked + *`;
    })
  });
});
module.exports = {
  variants: {
    extend:{
      border: ['nextOnChecked'],
      backgroundColor: ['nextOnChecked'],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    nextOnChecked
  ],
};
```

This part `.${e('nextOnChecked${separator}${className}')}:checked + *` will be used, in the context of this example, as the following :

```css
.nextOnChecked\:bg-blue-500:checked + *{
   background-color: ...;
}
```

That's how I build most of my variants, from the DOM that changes the state to the DOM that is being re-styled.

Answer (score 1):

Since Tailwind v2.1 the JIT engine supports the `peer` variant, who works similarly to `group`, but is based on state of direct sibling.
Ex.:

```html
<input id="choice-yes" type="radio" class="peer opacity-0 w-0 fixed" />

<label for="choice-yes" class="peer-checked:bg-[#bfb] border peer-checked:border-[#4c4] transition  duration-500 bg-blue-300 hover:bg-blue-500 w-20 h-20 rounded-full mr-5 flex items-center align-middle justify-center">Yes</label>
```

Source: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#sibling-selector-variants