# Targetting next sibling on hover with tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to hide an element until its previous sibling is hovered over, in css (or scss rather), it looks like this:

```css
.menu-container {
  // style with flex etc...
  & .menu-item-link {
    // style the link...
    &+.sub-menu-container {
      display: none;
    }
    &:hover+.sub-menu-container {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-container">
  <li class="menu-item-container">
    <a class="menu-item-link">Ingredients</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-container">
      <li class="sub-menu-item-container">
        <a class="sub-menu-link">Fruits</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-menu-item-container">
        <a class="sub-menu-link">Vegetables</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-menu-item-container">
        <a class="sub-menu-link">Dairy</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sub-menu-item-container">
        <a class="sub-menu-link">Children</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How do I achieve this using tailwind?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334626/tailwind-css-is-there-a-way-to-target-next-sibling).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind CSS : Is there a way to target next sibling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63334626/tailwind-css-is-there-a-way-to-target-next-sibling)

Comment: @Viira kind of: I accepted an answer provided below as it is a much saner way of solving my particular problem (using groups and targeting children as opposed to siblings)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not actually trying to target a sibling in your code, you're trying to target a child element. This is a very simple process when you just want to show a sub-menu dropdown.

Just add `group` to the hover trigger (.menu-item-link in your case) and `group-hover:[some-display-class]` to the child. This way the child will change it's display property when the parent element (or itself) is hovered.

You should change your title, also I'd recommend that you don't use Tailwind with class names like that. Please see [extracting components](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components) for the recommended way to use Tailwind CSS. Of course, you are free to use it how you want but you're better off with plain old CSS if you want to use SCSS and classes like that.

Example with your structure:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="group">
    <a>Ingredients</a>
    <ul class="hidden group-hover:block">
      <li>
        <a>Fruits</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Vegetables</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Dairy</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Children</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Example on Tailwind Play https://play.tailwindcss.com/dFc2zlmqDA

Comment: Yes that seems a far better way to handle this